# Access react devtools `$r` from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

I'm trying to programmatically access the name of the currently inspected component from ReactDevTools (i.e, `$r.type.name`).

How can I programmatically active ReactDevtools to access this value?

Comment: One extension can't directly extract data from another extension that runs in a devtools panel. Try asking on React Devtools developer site if it's exposing this info somehow via a global variable in page context or if it exposes its own API usable by other extensions.

Comment: would it be possible to get the chrome window to save a value from that extension and then get my extension to grab from the window?